# User account delete in django's rest

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want create view which can deactivation user's account. when i create view and send delete request i have error - > **"detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."**. i have authenticated permissionn but i am login in my account. i also use APIview

this is code ->

```
class DeleteAccount(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]


    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user=self.request.user
        user.delete()

        return Response({"result":"user delete"})
```

Comment: have you added authentication token in the header of your request?

Comment: @NischayNamdev yes

Comment: try removing overridden delete method. you are already using generic view. also check if you have added `as_view()` in your url.py file

Comment: @NischayNamdev yes this is url -> path('deleteuser/',DeleteAccount.as_view(), name="delete-user")

Comment: Delete user endpoint doesn't have id.. Give some id to the endpoint.

Comment: `'deleteuser/<int:pk>/'`. And remove the delete method from the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to be using a purely view-based approach, APIView might do the trick instead of the generic class. Additionally, setting the serializer class isn't necessary as well.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
```

```
class DeleteAccount(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user=self.request.user
        user.delete()

        return Response({"result":"user delete"})
```

Additionally as a general practice, it's better/safer to reserve user deletion capabilities only for admin/staff users.

Comment: same result.nothing change

Comment: note that you should use DELETE metod